# Why is the English word 'second' latin based but other numbers aren't?

Tags: etymology, numbers, latin, ordinal-numbers

Examples: one, two, three, etc. and first, third, fourth, etc. are all germanic and old english based, but "second" is Latin based. This also applies to "quarter" and I'm sure some others.

Comment: Borrowings, unlike sound changes, are intrinsically irregular. Which words get borrowed is not random, but it appears to be random to us, because we don't know the circumstances that produced the borrowing and kept it in the vocabulary.

Comment: I've always wondered why it isn't the "twoth".

Comment: Excellent question! Someone may or may not have an explanation, but it is a valid and interesting question at any rate. (As to quarter, I think that is somewhat less remarkable, because *a fourth* is also in use. Unless you meant the Mediaeval procedure.)

Comment: @Cerberus I'd have backed Tolkien against John Lawler on this one. If he'd given a different answer. Which I suspect he wuddna.

Comment: @HotLicks: But which twoth? There are so many. Maybe the twoth bicuspid?

Comment: @Drew - Let me chew on that one a bit.

Comment: Aren't both six->sixth and nine-ninth derived from Latin?  Three->third seems somewhat Latinate too, as e.g. triangle & trident.

Comment: @jamesqf: no; the Latin words for "six(th)," "nine(th)" and "third" resemble the English ones because the languages are related. Neither language borrowed these words from the other.

Answer (score 3):

[EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=second) explains what happened in their entry for "second":

> Replaced native [other](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=other) in this sense because of the ambiguousness of the earlier word.

Of course, we still have "other" (but it is no longer synonymous with "second").

Similarly, another, less ambiguous word (quarter) was introduced, as opposed to the original "a fourth" (which is easily confused with 4<sup>th</sup>).

Comment: Ah, I suppose that makes sense. Something similar probably happened in Latin, where *alter* "other" is normally used to mean "second", but the word *secundus* "second" is also used; *secundus* means something like "following" (cf. English *con**sec**utive, per**sec**ute*).